# SQL date flags for activity

Tags: sql

I'm curious about something.  Say I have a table with dates that indicate an "active" status on a record:

```
tbl_test
id   field1    active_dt    inactive_dt
AAA   asdf      2013-01-01    2013-02-12
AAA   sdf       2013-02-12    3000-01-01
BBB   dskjf     2012-01-01    3000-01-01
```

Each ID can have multiple records.  The "active" record is the one with an inactive date far in the future.  When I query this data to get only the active record, I use:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_test
WHERE
  inactive_dt >= '3000-01-01'
```

However, my question is this.  Is there any performance value for also limiting the `active_dt` field like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl_test
WHERE
  inactive_dt >= '3000-01-01'
  AND active_dt <= '3000-01-01'
```

Would this kind of limiting improve performance at all?  It was suggested to me by someone on my data warehouse team and I was curious if it was correct and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use equality:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_test
WHERE inactive_dt = '3000-01-01';
```

You don't mention indexes or the database you are using.  For all databases, no index on `inactive_dt` will result in a full table scan, and all the various methods are equivalent.

With an index, you are better off with equality, because databases support different types of indexes.  For instance, the Postgres hash-index doesn't handle inequalities as well as equalities.  The default, though, in most databases is a b-tree index.  With such an index, the equality and inequality would be pretty similar in performance.

But, there is another advantage to using equality.  That allows you to make better use of composite indexes.